# Android ndk freetype2

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, freetype

I'm trying to add freetype2 support in Android NDK.

I've successfully build the library, but how should I include it in Android.mk file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libFreeType
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libFreeType.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Later on:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += FreeType
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the Android.mk file, by putting it into the gradle file?